# How to generate symfony2 translations inside controller?

Tags: symfony, translation

Symfony2 project. I'm using JMSTranslationsBundle.

Here is a fragment from function **inside controller**:

```
if ($user->isAccountConfirmed()) {
            $this->toolbar->addInfo('user.account.confirmed');
        }
```

How to generate translation for 'user.account.confirmed' in .xliff file? I mean, what code I should add to this function to be able to translate it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the [available extraction methods](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSTranslationBundle/master/usage#extracting-translation-messages), it explains that there is no automatic extraction for your case available.

You will need to use [`trans`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#twig-templates) (or any of the other methods explained) in your template or in the controller. Without this hint, the extractor will not be able to find your message. Personally I have used [TranslationContainerInterface](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSTranslationBundle/blob/master/Translation/TranslationContainerInterface.php) in one my projects.

With that you simply define a new method in your controller, which returns the "to-be-translated" strings:

```
<?php
// ...
use JMS\TranslationBundle\Translation\TranslationContainerInterface;
use JMS\TranslationBundle\Model\Message;

class AcmeController extends Controller implements TranslationContainerInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    static function getTranslationMessages()
    {
        return [
            Message::create('user.account.confirmed')
        ];
    }
}
```

---

An alternate solution would be to directly use the [translater service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/translation/usage.html). The call to this service should then again be visible to the extractor. E.g:

```
/** @var $translator \Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface */
$translator = $this->get('translator');

if ($user->isAccountConfirmed()) {
    $this->toolbar->addInfo(
        $translator->trans('user.account.confirmed')
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's great. But I would like to do it another way (maybe not so great). My question is how to add 'trans' correctly to this line. I mean I can't use it like that: $this->toolbar->addInfo('user.account.confirmed')->trans('user.account.confirmed'); :D What the corrent way?

Comment: I will check it. Thank you.

Comment: I did it this way:

if ($user->isAccountConfirmed()) {
            $this->toolbar
                ->addInfo($this->toolbar->trans('user.account.confirmed'));
        }


What do you think @Yoshi ?

Comment: I'm not sure, it seems you added a trans-method to your toolbar-service (?). If that's the case, I don't think it's a good api, for translation is a duty of the translator service not your toolbar.