# Symfony 2 JMSTranslationsBundle Form with choice how to create translation terms?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, translation

I have a simple form with a choice type which is an simple entity:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name', 'entity', [
            'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Type',
                'property' => 'name',
                'expanded' => true
        ]
    );
}
```

The entity `type` is a database table with just an `idType AI column` and a `name column`.

The database content is also pretty simple:

```
idType      name
"1"         "term.inquiry"
"2"         "term.tender"
```

And the result in a twig file looks pretty simple too:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.name) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

I'm really stucked in how to implement the translation method to translate the `term.inquiry` and `term.tender`

I've looked up the documentation [here](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSTranslationBundle/master/usage#extracting-translation-messages), but I don't know how to implement (the correct way) the `getTranslationMessages` method via the `TranslationContainerInterface`. I've also tried the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33540385/how-to-generate-symfony2-translations-inside-controller/33540798#33540798) but didn't know how to match the return array with the choices in my `buildForm` method.

Any suggestions or hints for a best practice implementation?
Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you're maybe searching for the option `choice_translation_domain` introduced in symfony 2.7 as well as `choice_label` deprecating `property`.

see http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-translation-domain

if your translations are in `src/AppBundle/Resources/translations/entity.en.yml`, containing :

```
term:
    inquiry: 'A name'
    tender: 'Another name'
```

You can write something like :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Type',
            //'property' => 'name', is deprecated use 'choice_label' instead
            'expanded' => true,
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'choice_translation_domain' => 'entity',
        ));
}
```

Comment: Indeed this would be possible, but how I can extract translation terms from a php file, when I'm trying to generate them via:
`php app/console translation:extract de en --keep --bundle=AppBundle --dir=./src/AppBundle --output-dir=./app/Resources/translations` ?

Comment: they get automatically translated via the above command into /app/Resources/translations/messages.[lang_abbrev].xlf.
Indeed I can manually add the terms into those files, but how can I achieve, that they are generated?

The usage guideline of JMT Bundle says, that it is possible that terms from php code can be extracted

Comment: what symfony version are you using ? please try `'choice_translation_domain' => 'messages'`

Comment: 2.7.x - I tried your advice, but I get the following exception while trying to extract the translations via console:
`[JMS\TranslationBundle\Exception\RuntimeException]
  Unable to extract translation id for form label from non-string values, but got "PHPParser_Node_Expr_MethodCall" in
   ./src/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php on line 24. Please refactor your code to pass a string, or add "/
  ** @Ignore */".`

Comment: line 24 says:
`$form = $this->createFormBuilder()->add('variant', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => array(
                    0 => $this->get('translator')->trans('term.inquiry'), /* line 24 */
                    1 => $this->get('translator')->trans('term.tender'),
                ),
                'expanded' => true,
                'choice_translation_domain' => 'messages',
            ))
            ->getForm();`